# How to set anchor pane visible just before subprogram call in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

The purpose of the following code is to handle menu option choice. Because processing in method `update()` takes quite a bit time, I want to display info before this takes place.

My info is simply an anchor pane with label in it, which normally is set to be not visible. Unfortunately, the code below sets anchor pane visible only for a very short time after `update()` terminates. How can I do it properly?

```
public void updateRates(ActionEvent event)
{
    updateInfo.setVisible(true);
    update();
    updateInfo.setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most user interface libraries are single threaded.  That thread is created by and controlled by the UI system.  All listeners are called on that thread.  When the UI thread is held up, such as when your `update()` call is running, the UI does not redraw at all, and keyboard events and mouse events will “pile up” in the event queue, appearing to be ignored, until the thread is allowed to continue running (at which point all of them will be processed immediately, in order).

For this reason, lengthy operations must never execute on the UI thread.  One option is to run a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) in a different thread:

```
Task<Boolean> updater = new Task<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        updateValue(true);
        update();
        return false;
    }
};

updateInfo.visibleProperty().bind(updater.valueProperty());

new Thread(updater).start();
```

You could also create a Thread from a plain Runnable:

```
updateInfo.setVisible(true);

Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        update();
        Platform.runLater(() -> updateInfo.setVisible(false));
    }
};

new Thread(updater).start();
```

[Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) is required in this case, because user interface objects, including all JavaFX Nodes, may only be accessed and modified in the UI thread.  If your `update()` method is manipulating any Nodes, it will need to use Platform.runLater to do so.

The Task class has built-in support for showing work progress in the UI, but since you haven’t included the code for your `update()` method, I can’t tell you whether that support would be useful in your situation.